# Matlab and C++ yield different outcomes when optimizing Schwefel function by an algorithm similar to PSO

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, optimization, particle-swarm

This question might be long and I really appreciate your patience. The core problem is I used matlab and c++ to implement an optimization algorithm but they provided me different results(matlab's better).

I am recently studying some evolutionary algorithms and interested in one variant of PSO(Particle Swarm Optimization), which is called Competitive Swarm Optimizer(born in 2015). This is the paper link http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6819057.

The basic idea of this algorithm is to first generate some random particles in searching space and assign them random velocities. At each iteration, we randomly pair them and let every pair of particles compare their objective function values. Winners(with better objective values) keep status quo while losers update themselves by learning from winners(moving toward winners).

[Suppose at iteration t, particle i and j are compared and i is better. Then we update particle j for iteration t+1 by following these formulas. If particle j is out of searching space, we simply pull it back to the boundary. R_1, R_2, R_3 are all random vectors uniformly drawn from [0, 1]; operation 'otimes' means elementwise product; phi is a parameter; x_bar is the center of swarm.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNOhl.png)

For example, suppose now I want to minimize a 500-d Schwefel function(minimize the maximal absolute element) and I use 250 particles, set phi=0.1, searching space is 500-d [-100, 100]. Matlab could return me something around 35 while C++ got stuck at 85 to 90. I cannot figure out what's the problem.

Let me attach my matlab and c++ code here.

```
Sch = @(x)max(abs(x))
lb = -100 * ones(1, 500);
ub = 100 * ones(1, 500);
swarmsize = 250;
phi = 0.1;
maxiter = 10000;
tic
cso(Sch, lb, ub, swarmsize, phi, maxiter);
toc



function [minf, minx] = cso(obj_fun, lb, ub, swarmsize, phi, maxiter)
assert(length(lb) == length(ub), 'Not equal length of bounds');
if all(ub - lb <= 0) > 0
    error('Error. \n Upper bound must be greater than lower bound.')
end
vhigh = abs(ub - lb);
vlow = -vhigh;
S = swarmsize;
D = length(ub);
x = rand(S, D);
x = bsxfun(@plus, lb, bsxfun(@times, ub-lb, x)); % randomly initalize all particles
v = zeros([S D]); % set initial velocities to 0
iter = 0;
pairnum_1 = floor(S / 2);
losers = 1:S;
fx = arrayfun(@(K) obj_fun(x(K, :)), 1:S);
randperm_index = randperm(S);
while iter <= maxiter
    fx(losers) = arrayfun(@(K) obj_fun(x(K, :)), losers);
    swarm_center = mean(x); % calculate center all particles 
    randperm_index = randperm(S); % randomly permuate all particle indexes
    rpairs = [randperm_index(1:pairnum_1); randperm_index(S-pairnum_1+1:S)]'; % random pair
    cmask= (fx(rpairs(:, 1)) > fx(rpairs(:, 2)))'; 
    losers = bsxfun(@times, cmask, rpairs(:, 1)) + bsxfun(@times, ~cmask, rpairs(:, 2)); % losers who with larger values
    winners = bsxfun(@times, ~cmask, rpairs(:, 1)) + bsxfun(@times, cmask, rpairs(:, 2)); % winners who with smaller values
    R1 = rand(pairnum_1, D);
    R2 = rand(pairnum_1, D);
    R3 = rand(pairnum_1, D);
    v(losers, :) = bsxfun(@times, R1, v(losers, :)) + bsxfun(@times, R2, x(winners, :) - x(losers, :)) + phi * bsxfun(@times, R3, bsxfun(@minus, swarm_center, x(losers, :)));
    x(losers, :) = x(losers, :) + v(losers, :);
    maskl = bsxfun(@lt, x(losers, :), lb);
    masku = bsxfun(@gt, x(losers, :), ub);
    mask = bsxfun(@lt, x(losers, :), lb) | bsxfun(@gt, x(losers, :), ub);
    x(losers, :) = bsxfun(@times, ~mask, x(losers, :)) + bsxfun(@times, lb, maskl) + bsxfun(@times, ub, masku);
    iter = iter + 1;    
    fprintf('Iter: %d\n', iter);
    fprintf('Best fitness: %e\n', min(fx));
end
fprintf('Best fitness: %e\n', min(fx));
[minf, min_index] = min(fx);
minx = x(min_index, :);
end
```

(I didn't write C++ function.)

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define rand_01 ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX)  // generate 0~1 random numbers
#define PI 3.14159265359

const int numofdims = 500;  // problem dimension
const int numofparticles = 250;  // number of particles
const int halfswarm = numofparticles / 2;
const double phi = 0.1;
const int maxiter = 10000; // iteration number



double Sch(double X[], int d); // max(abs(x_i))


using namespace std;

int main(){
clock_t t1,t2;
t1=clock();

srand(time(0)); // random seed

double** X = new double*[numofparticles];  // X for storing all particles
for(int i=0; i<numofparticles; i++)
    X[i] = new double[numofdims];

double** V = new double*[numofparticles]; // V for storing velocities
for(int i=0; i<numofparticles; i++)
    V[i] = new double[numofdims];

double Xmin[numofdims] = {0}; // lower bounds
double Xmax[numofdims] = {0}; // upper bounds

double* fitnesses = new double[numofparticles];  // objective function values

for(int j=0; j<numofdims; j++)
{
    Xmin[j] = -100;
    Xmax[j] = 100;
}

for(int i=0; i<numofparticles; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<numofdims; j++)
    {
        X[i][j] = Xmin[j] + rand_01 * (Xmax[j] - Xmin[j]);  // initialize X
        V[i][j] = 0; // initialize V
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<numofparticles; i++)
{
    fitnesses[i] = Sch(X[i], numofdims); //
}

double minfit = fitnesses[0]; // temporary minimal value
int minidx = 0; // temporary index of minimal value

int* idxofparticles = new int[numofparticles];

for(int i=0; i<numofparticles; i++)
    idxofparticles[i] = i;

double* Xmean = new double[numofdims];

int* losers = new int[halfswarm]; // for saving losers indexes

for(int iter=0; iter<maxiter; iter++)
{

    random_shuffle(idxofparticles, idxofparticles+numofparticles);

    for(int j=0; j<numofdims; j++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<numofparticles; i++)
        {
            Xmean[j] += X[i][j];
        }
        Xmean[j] = (double) Xmean[j] / numofparticles;  // calculate swarm center
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < halfswarm; i++)
    {
        // indexes are now random
        // compare 1st to (halfswarm+1)th, 2nd to (halfswarm+2)th, ...
        if(fitnesses[idxofparticles[i]] < fitnesses[idxofparticles[i+halfswarm]])
        {

            losers[i] = idxofparticles[i+halfswarm];
            for(int j = 0; j < numofdims; j++)
            {
                V[idxofparticles[i+halfswarm]][j] = rand_01 * V[idxofparticles[i+halfswarm]][j] + rand_01 * (X[idxofparticles[i]][j] - X[idxofparticles[i+halfswarm]][j]) + rand_01 * phi * (Xmean[j] - X[idxofparticles[i+halfswarm]][j]);
                X[idxofparticles[i+halfswarm]][j] = min(max((X[idxofparticles[i+halfswarm]][j] + V[idxofparticles[i+halfswarm]][j]), Xmin[j]), Xmax[j]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            losers[i] = idxofparticles[i];
            for(int j = 0; j < numofdims; j++)
            {
                V[idxofparticles[i]][j] = rand_01 * V[idxofparticles[i]][j] + rand_01 * (X[idxofparticles[i+halfswarm]][j] - X[idxofparticles[i]][j]) + rand_01 * phi * (Xmean[j] - X[idxofparticles[i]][j]);
                X[idxofparticles[i]][j] = min(max((X[idxofparticles[i]][j] + V[idxofparticles[i]][j]), Xmin[j]), Xmax[j]);
            }
        }

    }
    // recalculate particles' values
    for(int i=0; i<numofparticles; i++)
    {
        fitnesses[i] = Sch(X[i], numofdims);
        if(fitnesses[i] < minfit)
        {
            minfit = fitnesses[i]; // update minimum
            minidx = i; // update index
        }
    }


    if(iter % 1000 == 0)
    {
        cout << scientific << endl;
        cout << minfit << endl;

    }
}
cout << scientific << endl;
cout << minfit << endl;

t2=clock();

delete [] X;
delete [] V;
delete [] fitnesses;
delete [] idxofparticles;
delete [] Xmean;
delete [] losers;

float diff ((float)t2-(float)t1);
float seconds = diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout << "runtime: " << seconds << "s" <<endl;

return 0;
}




double Sch(double X[], int d)
{
    double result=abs(X[0]);
    for(int j=0; j<d; j++)
    {
        if(abs(X[j]) > result)
            result = abs(X[j]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

So, finally, why can't my c++ code reproduce matlab's outcome? Thank you very much.

Comment: `double` is not a good datatype to use when accuracy is important.

Comment: @DrewDormann is that the same `double` as MATLAB uses?

Comment: @DrewDormann Brilliant! I changed to long double type and now it's working. Thank you so much!